# Regex - checking range of numbers with constraints

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript I need to parse a user input. The input is of the format: `number - number`. This can be repeated and separated by commas. 
The following are some examples:

```
1-10
4-10,13-17
6-10,3-8,4-12
```

Here is the regex I wrote for this

```
(\d+[-]\d+[,]?)
```

However, there are 2 constraints.

1. The first number must be less than the second number ( 4-5 is valid but 5-4 is not)
2. Every number must be between 1 and N (inclusive). I will specify N.

Is there a way I can enforce these constraints with regex?

Comment: A regex for a number range must be generated before it is used. Since this is not trivial, this should be hardcoded. Like say you have N where N is 20 to 67, you would need 67-20, or 47 regexes on hand to select from.

Comment: Why do you think you want to use regexp for this?

Comment: @torazaburo I figured regex wouldn't be able to have any constraints added, so I should have worded my question better. Sebastian pointed me into the right direction will using regex like I wanted to. I have very little experience with js and regex so I wasn't entirely sure how to do this or a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can certainly match the format with regexes, you can't do the kind of verification you want with them. What I would recommend is something like this (in JS):

```
function verifyList(list) {
    var matches = list.match(/\d+-\d+/g);
    for (match in matches) {
        var numbers = match.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/);
        if (numbers[1] >= numbers[2]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```